# Lightning datatable displaying rows but values are not visible

Tags: aura, lightning-datatable, data, dynamic-soql

I am trying to display Account records through dynamic SOQL, and I am getting the queried data in the console. Also, the result screen is displaying the rows with respect to that data, but the values in it aren't visible.

I am attaching the screenshot of the result screen, and I am adding my code below for reference. Can anyone please let me know what's wrong here?

**App**

```
<aura:application extends='force:slds'>
    <c:RakitaCompNineteen/>
</aura:application>
```

**Component**

```
<aura:component controller='RakitaCompNineteenMain'>
    <aura:attribute name='searchText' type='String' />
    <aura:attribute name='accounts' type='Account[]'/>
    <aura:attribute name='fields' type='List' default='["Name", "Industry", "Phone"]'/>
    <aura:attribute name='flag' type='Boolean'/>
    <lightning:card>
        <aura:set attribute='title'>
            <ui:inputText value='{!v.searchText}'/>
            <ui:button label='Search' press='{!c.invoke}'/>
        </aura:set>
        <aura:if isTrue='{!v.flag}'>
            <lightning:datatable keyField="id" data="{! v.accounts }" columns="{! v.fields }" />    
        </aura:if>
    </lightning:card>
</aura:component>
```

**Controller**

```
({
    invoke : function(component, event, helper) {
        var searchText = component.get('v.searchText');
        var abc = component.get('c.returnAccounts');
        abc.setParams({'searchStr':searchText});
        abc.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if(state === 'SUCCESS') {
                var returnVal = response.getReturnValue();
                component.set('v.accounts', returnVal);
            }
            component.set('v.flag', true);
            console.log(returnVal);
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(abc);
    }
})
```

Apex Class

```
public class RakitaCompNineteenMain {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Account> returnAccounts(String searchStr) {
        String query = 'SELECT Id, Name, Industry, Phone From Account WHERE Name LIKE \'%' + searchStr + '%\'';
        List<Account> accts = Database.query(query);
        return accts;
    }
}
```

Screenshot of the result screen

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fields value which is passed columns attribute of data table could be the problem. Try creating your fields like below (label, fieldname and type). fieldname in lowercase.

[image]